# Fixing "Bad Sectors" found during External HDD Formatting, Windows 10 CMD Prompt

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs, formatting

I recently was trying to reformat a external 3TB WD MyBook (USB) via Windows Command Line

I used the command

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>format g: /FS:NTFS /X
```

and received the following output

> ```
> The type of the file system is RAW.
> The new file system is NTFS.
> WARNING, ALL DATA ON NON-REMOVABLE DISK
> DRIVE G: WILL BE LOST!
> Proceed with Format (Y/N)? Y
> Formatting 2.7 TB
> 5860464640 bad sectors were encountered during the format.  These sectors
> cannot be guaranteed to have been cleaned.
> ```

Is there a way to fix these sectors? I was reformatting the drive to clear out all the old files that were no longer needed on this device and we becoming time consuming to try and delete manually. I wanted to set the External Drive up as new.

Comment: Bad sectors can't be fixed. At best they can be marked as unusable while formatting. You can keep using it but keep in mind the drive can't no longer be trusted. Check its health regularly and if the bad sectors count keeps increasing replace it at your convenience.

Comment: If I am understanding the message - this drive is next to dead? Especially with the number of sectors?

Comment: The RAW file-system is already a good indication that the disk had a catastrophic crash.

Comment: That is an extraordinary high number of bad sectors. May I suggest that you pick out the drive from "MyBook" (I suspect the electronics to be bad) and move the drive into a replacement (20€) casing. I've had one MyBook's and it got unreliable, the actual HDD is still in use... and have more HDD:s of the same type.

Comment: I had the same experience as @Hannu but with a Seagate external drive. I'm still using the HDD but now in a desktop PC.